# Python df loop and apply 'pct_change' function to specific rows -- AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'pct_change'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

this is my first question and I am new to coding (3mo.) so bare with me if I am not explaining myself all that well..

I am working with a large stock options df and would like to loop through each row and apply the 'pct_change()' function to rows where the 'optionalias' == the previous row 'optionalias'. I have made a separate column labeled 'match' to identify where this is True.

```
index, optionalias, quotedate, last, match, percent_change
0   SPY200103P00260000  2020-01-03  0.01    False   0
1   SPY200103P00265000  2020-01-02  0.01    False   0
2   SPY200103P00265000  2020-01-03  0.01    True    0
3   SPY200103P00270000  2020-01-02  0.01    False   0
4   SPY200103P00272500  2020-01-02  0.01    False   0
5   SPY200103P00272500  2020-01-03  0.01    True    0
6   SPY200103P00275000  2020-01-02  0.01    False   0
```

**put_options_df_image:**

[image]

The 'pct_change()' function will be calculated for each unique 'optionalias' rather than the entire data set.

I attempted to create a for loop that applies the 'pct_change()' function to rows where the 'match' column == True but I receive the following error even though the column 'last' is a **float64** data type.

```
for i, row in puts_grouped.iterrows():
    return_val = 0
    if row['match'] == True:
        return_val = row['last'].pct_change() * 100
    row.set_value(i,'percent_change', return_val)
```

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'pct_change'
**AttributeErrorImage:**

[image]

**Alternatives I have tried:**

- Instead of creating a for loop, I have tried using the groupby().pct_change() but it produces a weird output.

**Groupby.Pct_change:**

[image]

```
puts_grouped = df_historical_puts.groupby(['optionalias', 'quotedate'])[['last']].pct_change()
```

- A different for loop that either gets stuck or runs forever?

```
for i in range(1, len(puts_grouped)):
    if puts_grouped.loc[i, 'optionalias'] == puts_grouped.loc[i-1, 'optionalias']:
        puts_grouped.loc[i, 'percent_change'] = (puts_grouped.loc[i, 'last'] - puts_grouped.loc[i-1, 'last']) / puts_grouped.loc[i-1, 'last'] * 100
```

- Yet, another for loop with no success:

```
for i in puts_grouped['match']:
    
    put_option_returns = []
    
    if i == True:
        returns = puts_grouped['last'].pct_change() * 100
        put_option_returns.append(returns)
    else:
        returns = 0
        put_option_returns.append(returns)
```

I would appreciate any guidance on what I should do differently for any of the approaches I have attempted. Thank you all.

Comment: if your dates are sorted in ascending order you don't need the date column inside the group: `df_historical_puts.groupby("optionalias")['last'].pct_change()` should work

Answer (score 0):

pct_change() function works for dataframe but you are applying it to a float object.
What you can do maybe is create another dataframe which have all rows as match = True by

```
puts_grouped1 = puts_grouped[(puts_grouped['match'] == True)]
```

And then apply pct_change() on this puts_grouped1

```
puts_grouped1['last'].pct_change()
```

Remember that the pct_change() calculates percetage change of the current element and prior element so the first output you shall get will always be NaN